# What are the limits of free PaaS with Event Driven server/applications?

Tags: node.js, heroku, tornado, event-driven, cloudcontrol

I ask this question, because Heroku or CloudControl are not really explicit on how a free application can consume their ressources?!

The application will use event driven based server ([Node](http://nodejs.org/) or [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)), and event driven is monothreaded, so here is my questions:

1. How many users in a day can a free application handle, since event driven are not heavy for the CPU, nor for Memory?
2. In Tornado (I dont know about Node), you can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` that can use another thread in case of time consuming operations, will the free offer allow me to use this option? Or i will be limited for one thread only?

Answer (score 1):

cloudControl works with containers (LXC), the application is started within such a container and the resources CPU, Memory, Network are restricted to the configured scaling options. Memory is a hard limit, for CPU and Network you get a guaranteed share, if more is available, you get more.

Inside the container you can start and use what you want and need.
If you can handle the requests with this limited resources and don't need fault tolerance, you can stick with the free tier.

Comment: but how is the physical limit of that in term of number of visitor, operation, by day?

Comment: This is a tricky question, as always 'it depends'.

It depends heavily on your application. In most of the web applications CPU it not necessary the limiting factor and Memory is just a limit which you need to know. In most of the cases the application is using some additional services like databases, APIs, caching services, which influence the response time. Our rule of thumb is, that one container is similar to one CPU core.

Comment: which means i cant call multi processing?

Comment: Yes, No, it depends. It is possible that you can get shares of multiple CPUs. I would suggest: try it out, one container is free. But before you dig to deep into getting the last bit out of one container, the Idea of PaaS is horizontal scaling. If you need more power just add a couple of container. So If you want to use PaaS you should start from the beginning think about, if your implementation also would work with multiple containers.